# How to get locator annotation of WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "element-id")
private WebElement element;

public boolean isElementExists() {
    try { 
       this.driver.findElement(element.getAnnotationLocator());
       return true;       
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm using AjaxElementLocatorFactory so simply putting element.getTagName() inside try and catch takes too long. Is there way to get the locator annotation of the WebElement?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? It might be that you have implicit waits turned on so that your findElement is actually waiting for that element (default is 30 seconds I think) before returning the NoSuchElementException. Is that the issue?

Comment: My issue is that I'm using AjaxElementLocatorFactory in page factory. AjaxElementLocatorFactory waits for certain amount of time before throwing NoSuchElementException. And I want to write a function that checks if element is exists without waiting

Comment: Did you look into implicit and explicit waits like I suggested?